# Strategy pattern movies conditionals from inside the main class to the client code, so what's the point?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am trying to understand the strategy pattern, here is an example, we have a `Customer` that has a method `GetDiscount`, this method is written as follows

```
GetDiscount
    If (Condition1)
        Return 10%
    else (Condition2)
        Return 20%
```

Now I have refactored the code using the strategy pattern so it becomes

```
GetDiscount
     Invoke the attached strategy
```

And we create two strategy class `10%Strategy` and `20%Strategy` to encapsulate the behavior of the discount

And for the client code to use the customer class it becomes

```
c = new Customer

if(condition1)
c.attach(10%Strategy)
else (condition2)
c.attach(20%Strategy)

c.GetDiscount
```

So as you can see we have moved the conditionals from inside `Customer` class into the client code, not only this, but this conditional branching itself is considered a business logic and we let it to leak into client code that might be a presentation controller for example.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In large software systems developed with object-oriented techniques you have code that assembles objects, and code that uses the assembled objects. In your case, the code that calls `attach` is assembling `Customer` object for later use, and the code that calls `GetDiscount` is one that makes use of the object.

The goal the strategy pattern fulfills is moving the decision of which discount the `Customer` gets form the point where the object is used to the point where the object is assembled. The condition remains in your code, but it is now confined to the place where you create your `Customer` object.

Once the assembly is done, the `Customer` object becomes self-sufficient. The data that you used to compute the condition for 10% or 20% discount is no longer required, because it is embedded in the type of discount. The logic for computing a discount follows the `Customer` into different places in code. You can use discount computation without duplicating the logic in multiple places - for example, to compute the total price of sale, to preview the price of an individual item, to process a return, and so on. This also saves you from duplicating the same logic when the computation is needed more than once.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand, could you please explain more.

Comment: @user2080257 Please let me know what part of the explanation is not clear, I'll be happy to go into more detail.

Comment: pretty much all of it :) , if you can rephrase the two paragraphs in more details I will be very grateful.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to rephrase your answer, but don't you see with me that the problem is still there i.e. conditional still exists at assembling code? so we just moved the problem from one place to another. also do you think that the conditionals itself could be part of the business logic that we need to keep placed in the Customer object?

Comment: @user2080257 Absolutely, the conditional is still there, but it is moved to a place where we are in a better position to make a decision. For example, you could be reading `Customer` objects from DB, and decide their eligibility for deeper discount based on some complicated criteria. With a strategy, you do it once, and "remember" your decision by creating the right subclass of your strategy. At this point you can forget about the complex criteria for discount: it's part of your `Customer` object.

Comment: @user2080257 If you keep the condition in `GetDiscount` you would have to check eligibility every time you compute the discount. In addition, you will need to keep the data which you use to check eligibility for a discount, which would not be required if you use strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The core point:

```
c = new Customer
if(condition1)
  c.attach(10%Strategy)
else (condition2)
  c.attach(20%Strategy)
c.GetDiscount
```

is probably code that you **do not** write manually. In other words: in larger, "real world" applications you **avoid** calls to **new** for "real business" objects. Instead, you rely on frameworks that do **dependency injection** for you.

In other words: your deployed application has a certain *configuration*. And then *framework* code decides what kind of objects to create; and how to configure them.

In that sense, an alternative implementation could turn into:

```
if(condition1)
  c = new Customer10%
else (condition2)
  c = new Customer20%
c.GetDiscount
```

Meaning: you turn to polymorphism; and simply have your DI framework create that specific Customer class that is required based on "configuration knowledge".

Interestingly enough, some "further food for thought" regarding such concepts can be found in video no. 2 from these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) about writing testable code.